# Pandas read date from CSV and groupby total business days per month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

**data.CSV**

```
ID Activity Month   Activity Date

0   04/2019     04-01-2019

1   05/2019     05-13-2019

2   05/2019     05-25-2019

3   06/2019     06-10-2019

4   06/2019     06-19-2019

5   07/2019     07-15-2019

6   07/2019     07-18-2019

7   07/2019     07-29-2019

8   08/2019     06-03-2019

9   08/2019     06-15-2019

10  08/2019     06-20-2019
```

**MY PLAN**

Read csv:

> df = pd.read_csv('data.CSV')

Convert to datetime:

> df['Activity Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Activity Date'], dayfirst=True)

Groupby the Activity Month column:

> grouped = df.groupby(['Activity Month'])['Activity Date'].count()
>
> print(grouped)

```
Activity Month
04/2019    15532
05/2019    13924
06/2019    12822
07/2019    14067
08/2019    10939
Name: Activity Date, dtype: int64
```

While the date is grouped, perform business day calculation:

> This part i'm not sure what to do. Lost already

**CODE I USED TO CALCULATE BUSINESS DAYS**

```
import calendar
import datetime

x = datetime.date(2019, 4, 1)
cal = calendar.Calendar()
working_days = len([x for x in cal.itermonthdays2(x.year, x.month) if x[0] !=0 and x[1] < 5])
print ("Total business days for month (" + str(x.month) +  ") is " + str(working_days) + " days")
```

**OUTPUT THAT I WANTED**

```
Total business days for month (4) is 22 days
Total business days for month (5) is 23 days
Total business days for month (6) is 20 days
Total business days for month (7) is 23 days
Total business days for month (8) is 22 days
```

Comment: Commenting to not lost track of this, I'm on my phone, will check in some hours and give you answer. I recently also worked with this library!

Comment: Thanks for the effort @CeliusStingher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear and the problem statement here, but if you want to calculate the number of business days for each `Activity Month`, you can wrap your calculation in a method, and apply that method over your `Activity Month` column (the `lambda` expression is basically a for loop operation over each row for specified columns).

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Activity Month'])['Activity Date'].count().reset_index()

def get_business_days(x):
    x = datetime.date(int(x.split('/')[1]), int(x.split('/')[0]), 1)
    cal = calendar.Calendar()
    working_days = len([x for x in cal.itermonthdays2(x.year, x.month) if x[0] !=0 and x[1] < 5])
    return ("Total business days for month (" + str(x.month) +  ") is " + str(working_days) + " days")

grouped['Activity Month'].apply(get_business_days)
```

The output is a Series that has your text output.

```
0    Total business days for month (4) is 22 days
1    Total business days for month (5) is 23 days
2    Total business days for month (6) is 20 days
3    Total business days for month (7) is 23 days
4    Total business days for month (8) is 22 days
```

But, it's a bad idea to store repeated information in every cell. It'd be preferable to simply return `working_days` instead of having it embedded in a string.

Comment: I guess this is what I wanted. For learning purpose only so it's fine, for now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Anyway, may I know why we need to add ".reset_index()" please? I tried to remove that but then the code is not working

Comment: When you run the `groupby` operation it puts `Activity Month` as the index of the `DataFrame`. `reset_index()` swaps the current index out for the row number and puts that original index in as a new column (only if you don't pass `drop=True`).